# Visual Studio 2017 RC failed to load packages correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS2017 RC today, and it keeps showing errors for some packages not being loaded correctly. from many posts I saw here, the fix they suggested was to open developer and type

> devenv /setup

. but nothing happen,

> tried devenv /resetuserdata

still nothing happen. 
this is a pic of one of many errors:

```
<entry>
    <record>29</record>
    <time>2016/12/25 14:43:03.794</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>UserConnection</source>
    <description>Manager ServerUri &apos;https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=659577&apos;</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>30</record>
    <time>2016/12/25 14:43:03.794</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{B22490B8-AA51-43B1-97EE-509A33B681F3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2016/12/25 14:43:03.794</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Feedback.FeedbackPackage]</description>
    <guid>{B22490B8-AA51-43B1-97EE-509A33B681F3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2016/12/25 14:43:03.801</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{C3C7E24F-26F7-49D8-A1D6-A9C4ADCD9BC2}</guid>
  </entry>
```

I've uninstall the VS2017 RC and delete cache data as many post suggested but still no work. This is probably a repost, but can someone help me on this?